# Selecting items matching a specific condition from a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that contains keys like this:

```
237870a/
237870b/
237870c/
115460a/
115460b/
115460c/
115460d/
229898/
212365a/
109678/
```

I need to iterate over this list of keys and pull out certain items:

1. For items that share the same numeric prefix and have an alphabetic character at the end, I need the item with the highest character, i.e. in this case `237870c`, `115460d`, and `212365a`.
2. Any other item with a unique number without a trailing alphabetic character, i.e. `229898` & `109678`

So, my result should be:

```
237870c/
115460d/
229898/
212365a/
109678/
```

sorry I don't have any code to show as i'm really not sure how to even start writing this...

Comment: Copy the keys to a list. Sort the list. Iterate through it, comparing each item to the next, to see if they start with the same digits.

Comment: Do the actual keys contain the trailing ``/``? Is there always at most *one* alphabetic character?

Comment: @JonasWielicki yes, and yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this has nothing to do with dictionaries: as you said yourself, you’re operating on a list of keys. The origin of the list isn’t important.

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this, with a clever key function. For `itertools.groupby` to work properly, we first need to sort the keys:

```
keys = sorted(keys)
```

Then we have to think about a key function. This must be designed in a way so that only the numeric prefix is used to group:

```
def keyfunc(item):
    if item[-1].isalpha():
         return item[:-1]
    return item
```

This will strip the last character if it is alphabetic, so that `itertools.groupby` won’t take it into account when grouping. We’ll then take the last element of the grouped items, which will be the one with the highest alphabetic character.

Now we can apply groupby to obtain a list of items as you need:

```
items = [sorted(subitems)[-1] 
         for _, subitems 
         in itertools.groupby(keys, keyfunc)]
```

See it in action:

```
>>> # output formatting and indentation by me
... 
>>> keys
['237870a/', '237870b/', '237870c/', '115460a/', 
 '115460b/', '115460c/', '115460d/', '229898/', 
 '212365a/', '109678/']
>>> def keyfunc(item):
...   if item[-1].isalpha():
...     return item[:-1]
...   return item
... 
>>> items = [sorted(subitems)[-1] 
...          for _, subitems 
...          in itertools.groupby(keys, keyfunc)]
>>> items
['237870c/', '115460d/', '229898/', '212365a/', '109678/']
```

Comment: "This will strip the last character if it is alphabetic.", I don't want to strip off the last char.

Comment: @Radamand it's only stripped for the purposes of determining a group, not stripped from the final output - see the example.